# Stored procedure to delete duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help to fix my problem:

```
create procedure dbo.spDelDdup
    (@field1 nvarchar(50)= null,
     @field2 varchar(50),
     @tblName varchar(50))
as
BEGIN
    WITH CTE (@field1, @field2, Duplicate_Record_Count) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            @field1, @field2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY @field1, @field2 ORDER BY @field1) AS Duplicate_Record_Count
        FROM 
            @tblName
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE
    WHERE Duplicate_Record_Count > 1
END
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spDelDdup, Line 91
>   Incorrect syntax near '@field1'.

Would be nice to fix my problem

Comment: You could just remove `(@field1, @field2, Duplicate_Record_Count)`. It's only needed if you don't have unique column names in your query definition within the CTE. Also, when you SELECT `@field1`  or any variable you need to alias it in your CTE. i.e. `select @field1 as [someColumn]`. You are also going to run into problems trying to pass a table name into @tblName. You'll need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql) as below:

You have also declared `@field1` as optional parameter which you need to manage it, however it is a bit strange. But if this is exactly what you want, please leave a comment, so that I will update my answer based on it.

```
create procedure dbo.spDelDdup
(@field1 nvarchar(50)= null,
@field2 varchar(50),
@tblName varchar(50))
as
BEGIN
Declare @q AS Nvarchar(max)
Set @q = N'WITH CTE ('+@field1+', '+@field2+', Duplicate_Record_Count)
AS
(
    SELECT '+@field1+','+@field2+',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY '+@field1+','+@field2+' ORDER BY '+@field1+') AS Duplicate_Record_Count
    FROM '+@tblName+'
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE Duplicate_Record_Count > 1'

EXEC(@q);

END
```

You can also use [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) too.